# Alamofire callback after multiple requests finish

Tags: ios, swift, http, asynchronous, alamofire

I have to make a number of async requests to a server (let's say 20) and I need to wait for all them to finish (being successful or not) to trigger an action. I want to know if there's an elegant way of keeping a reference to all of them without keeping a variable in the parent's scope, i.e not like:

```
var numberOfCalls = 10

for i in 1...20 {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, url) { response in 
        numberOfCalls--
        if numberOfCalls == 0 {
             // do something
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using Alamofire, Swift 2, xcode 7

Comment: [Dispatch Groups](http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2014/03/19/using-dispatch-groups-to-wait-for-multiple-web-services/) ?

Comment: @GoodSp33d I would vote up twice if I could, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally wrapped my head around GCD handling multiple concurrent tasks on this post [Dispatch Groups](http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2014/03/19/using-dispatch-groups-to-wait-for-multiple-web-services/) suggested by @GoodSp33d